# append hidden content to meeting body in outlook using office js

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

using my outlook add-in I need to add some hidden data (some metadata) to meeting body. I tried adding `display:none` style to html element but no luck. is there any way to achieve this?
below is my code to set body content

```
  function addWorkspaceToItemBody(textToAppend) {
        var d = $q.defer();
          var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
        item.body.getTypeAsync(
            function (result) {
                if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                    write(result.error.message);
                }
                else {
                    // Successfully got the type of item body.
                    // Set data of the appropriate type in body.
                    if (result.value == Office.MailboxEnums.BodyType.Html) {
                        // Body is of HTML type.
                        // Specify HTML in the coercionType parameter
                        // of setSelectedDataAsync.
                        item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(
                            '<p style="display:none">'+textToAppend+'<\p>',
                            { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html, 
                            asyncContext: { var3: 1, var4: 2 } },
                            function (asyncResult) {
                                if (asyncResult.status == 
                                    Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                                    d.reject(asyncResult.error.message);
                                }
                                else {
                                    d.resolve(asyncResult)
                                    // Successfully set data in item body.
                                    // Do whatever appropriate for your scenario,
                                    // using the arguments var3 and var4 as applicable.
                                }
                            });
                    }
                    else {
                        // Body is of text type. 
                        item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(
                            "",
                            { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Text, 
                                asyncContext: { var3: 1, var4: 2 } },
                            function (asyncResult) {
                                if (asyncResult.status == 
                                    Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                                    d.reject(asyncResult.error.message);
                                }
                                else {
                                    d.resolve(asyncResult)
                                    // Successfully set data in item body.
                                    // Do whatever appropriate for your scenario,
                                    // using the arguments var3 and var4 as applicable.
                                }
                             });
                    }
                }
            });
            return d.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Could you share what your scenario is? By adding something as hidden, is there something you plan to do with it on the receiving end?

Comment: yes, In my plug in i have a dropdown, user selects some value in dropdown and clicks on submit button i need to send that selected value  and use it on the receiving end.

Comment: Do you target to add a hidden html element into the meeting body after clicking submit button, if I understand it correctly ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. I tried adding anchor tag without link text it is working for web versions of outlook but from windows outlook app it is not working.

Comment: Which clients and versions (e.g. Outlook 2013, Outlook 2016, etc.) are you targeting?

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example to insert hidden content using the following code. The content is hidden in Outlook 2016, OWA, and Outlook for Android. It may still show up if the content is viewed as plain text in other email clients.

```
var content = 
"<!--[if !mso 9]><!-->"+
'<div class="hidden" style="display:none;max-height:0px;overflow:hidden;">'+
"CONTENT HERE THAT YOU WANT TO HIDE"+
"</div>"+
"<!--<![endif]-->";

Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync("Hello World! " + content, function (asyncResult) {
  if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
    console.log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
  }
});
```

[Source](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/5284-hiding-elements-in-all-instances-of-outlook)

Comment: I recently added '<div style="mso-hide:all;display:none;max-height:0px;overflow:hidden;">SECRET TEXT</div>' 
It was getting hidden in boy , but it is getting displayed in the Mail list preview part in Outlook client.
Is there a way to hide there as well?
@Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT